# Google Earth Plugin not loading sideDatabase from Mapsengine/Earthbuilder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have not been able to successfully display my side database (map from Mapsengine/Earthbuilder).  I have installed Google Plugin and tried to access it from Firefox, Chrome, and IE browsers and nothing seems to work. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong as I have confirmed my code with the code used in Google's Code Playground, and I have attempted a workaround that was suggested in a similar issue from the past (Issue 21: GMaps Engine Layer Disappeared over GEarth plugin).  When specifing the URL of my map to be displayed in GE plugin, I even changed the URL to include &export=download, which is one of the fixes I saw in another similar issue (it was about kml files from google docs).

Strangely, when my webpage is accessed, it does not give an error that the side database failed to download.
I have included part of the code below.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CHO;
google.load("earth", "1");

function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
}

function initCB(instance) {
  CHO = instance;
  CHO.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

  CHO.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(CHO.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
  CHO.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(CHO.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
  CHO.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(CHO.LAYER_ROADS, true);

  addSideDatabase()


  // Add controls for the window
  CHO.getOptions().setStatusBarVisibility(true);
  CHO.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(CHO.VISIBILITY_AUTO);

  // Update the view in Google Earth
  var lookAt = CHO.createLookAt('');
  lookAt.setLatitude(30.0);
  lookAt.setLongitude(-90.0);
  lookAt.setRange(9500000); //default is 0.0
  CHO.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
  }

  function failureCB(errorCode) {
    alert(errorCode);
  }

  function sideDatabaseSuccess(db) {
  sideDatabase = db;
   db.setDrawOrder(2);
  }

  function sideDatabaseFail() {
     alert('Sorry! Side database failed to load!');
  }

  /** Add the URL for the globe served by Earth Enterprise or Earth Builder.
  *     This function operates similarly to the File => Add Database feature
  *     in Google Earth EC.
  */
  function addSideDatabase() {

    google.earth.addSideDatabase(
    CHO, "https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zHgXRX6Mts2Q.kHGFoYZlcyBQ&export=download",
  sideDatabaseSuccess,
  sideDatabaseFail,
  {
    userName: '',
    password: '' 
  }
);
  }google.setOnLoadCallback(init);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to load is a map, not a globe. The two are not equivalent. You can't load a map in Google Earth.

On the bright side, your side-loading code is spot on. Replace your URL with http://laearth.la.gov (Louisiana's Custom Google Earth Server) and it will work.

Comment: Hi Debracey, thank you for responding to my question. My goal is to load a map as a layer in Google Earth Plugin, and I learned about this GE Plugin feature from Google Earth Plugin Documentation (https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/) where it specifically mentions that Google Maps Engine maps can be loaded into GE plugin.  I followed Google's instructions on how to accomplish this task, but it never worked properly.

Comment: Hmm ok -- so it might work. The URL they use is very different though. Have you tried `https://mapsengine.google.com/map/zHgXRX6Mts2Q.kHGFoYZlcyBQ/kh/`? Notice they use earthbuilder, not mapsengine. Not sure how that comes into play.

Comment: Yes, I used the mapsengine URL, but it didn't work. I think earthbuilder was an earlier version of mapsengine. IF you try to go to earthbuilder.google.com it will take you to the mapsengine.  Aside from that, going by google documentation, the site should work (i.e. map layer downloaded in GE plugin), but it doesn't, which leads me to believe that there might be something wrong on Google's end, and if that's the case, then I'm surprised that I don't see more of questions like mine posted.

Comment: @Semir I have the exact same issue!  Did you make any headway with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is that URL for a Google Maps Engine Lite map?  If so, that might be the issue.  I just tried swapping in the URL (https://earthbuilder.google.com/10446176163891957399-13516001307527776624-4/kh/) used in the Google Code Playground example here http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#adding_a_side_database.  That one worked, but my Google Maps Engine Lite URL didn't.  Furthermore, it didn't even seem to call its success or failure callback functions!